# Retrofit form-data POST not return JSON

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, apache-commons-httpclient

I try this POST in a server using Apache HttpClient and working perfectly:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL + "access.php");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAMETER_COD, mAccessCode));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAMETER_USU, mUser));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAMETER_PAS, mPassword));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                //JSON RESPONSE
                String op = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //reset the message text field
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I tried make usin Retrofit and not working:

```
@Multipart
@POST("access.php")
Call<String> authenticate(@Part("cod") String cod, @Part("usu") String usu, @Part("pas") String pas);
```

private ApiInterface getInterfaceService() {

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    final ApiInterface mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    return mInterfaceService;
}

private void loginProcessWithRetrofit(final User user){

    ApiInterface mApiService = this.getInterfaceService();
    Call<String> mService = mApiService.authenticate(String.valueOf(user.cod),user.pas,user.usu);
    mService.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            //String returnedResponse = mLoginObject.isLogin;
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Returned " + response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showProgress(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your network connection and internet permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Retrofit",t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Also try this other post:

```
@POST("access.php")
Call<String> authenticate(@Body User user);
```

What is the correct form to conver my HttpPost to Retrofit. 
Thanks a lot.
 Regards

Comment: Can you try the UrlEncode annotation?

Comment: '@MultiPart' and '@FormURLEncoded' not working in same time. If I quit '@multipart'neither return JSON.

Comment: Well what does not work? You are so vague. Which response do you get in onResponse()?

Comment: This is RawResponse Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://****.****.***.dev/access.php} and Body return="OR"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("access.php")
Call<Object> authenticate(@Field("cod") String cod, @Field("usu") String usu, @Field("pas") String pas);
```

Comment: Not working. I change part to field and not return JSON.

Comment: You can change String to Object. But Is the request ok?

Comment: the Field annotation thing should make it work, try again with the edits @pablogupi

Comment: I try using Object and Field annotation and response is: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://*****.*******.*****.dev/access.php} but does not return the json

Comment: are you sure? retrofit would automatically convert the response from json to a java object, but you currently don't have a java object that represents the json so it can't map any of the fields to anything

Comment: if you use Gson. you can make body response to string json by : **new Gson().toJson(response.body())**

Comment: But response.body is "OR"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Call<JsonElement> mService
```

**Instead of **

```
Call<String> mService;
```

in all place.. where you add `<String>`

Comment: Same response as in previous cases. I think something is missing when doing the post because in the answer there is no trace of json